# How to Split String into Array of Strings in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a text file (I wish there was an xml) that I need to split to arrays, I really don't know how to start it and if its possible therefor I don't have any code

The pattern is like this:

```
ProductCode: google.googleDBAdapter (1)
    Patch Number: 1434766
        Package File: /DBAdapterConsumer
        Action: Copy
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/VSBMQProvider.dll
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/VSBMQProvider2.dll
ProductCode: google.googleElcServices (1)
    Patch Number: 1434766
        Package File: /ForwarderServiceVersion_8_6x
        Action: Copy
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/ADObjectsManagedWrapper.dll
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/AzureADExtractor.dll
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/AzureADExtractorWrapper.dll

        Package File: /ResolverService_8_6_x
        Action: Copy
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/Resolver.exe
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/google.Client.Common.dll

        Package File: /RealTimeAlertsServiceOld
        Action: Copy
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/VrnsRealTimeAlertsSvc.exe
ProductCode: google.googleSyncManager (1)
    Patch Number: 1434766
        Package File: /SyncManager
        Action: Copy
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/google.Core.Configuration.Builders.dll
            File:   ${TargetRootFolder}/google.ServiceBus.Extensions.dll
```

The idea is to read the name of a file and search if part of the name can be found at any of the 'Package File:' , if it does I need to search if the file name is equal the 'File' that located under the 'Package File:'

So I need to split the file to sections from 'Package File:' to 'Package File:' (at the end of the file there is no 'Package File:') and store the name of the package file (without the / ) then I need to store all the files under the package file name. I think this will let me to search what I need but I am not sure

Comment: A hashtable keyed on PackageName: `$FilePath = 'C:\Path\to\\Data.txt' ; $FIleLookup = Get-Content $FilePath | Select-String -Pattern '(?:Package\s+)?File.+/([^/]+)$' | ForEach-Object -Begin { $hash = @{} ; $currKey = ''} -Process { If ( $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value -match 'Package' ) { $currKey = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value ; $currVal = @() ; $hash.Add($currKey , $currVal) } Else { $currVal = $hash[$currKey] + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value ; $hash[$currKey] = $currVal } } -End { $hash } ; $FIleLookup` -- If only you were clear about your string matching...

Comment: File called package.json was tagged as package file...

Comment: Oops! It was getting late/early ( and it wasn't in your sample data). Easy fix, though. Change `If ( $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value -match 'Package' )` to `If ( $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value -match '^Package' )`.

Comment: Worked thank you. the $FIleLookup has Name and Value. how can I get to all the packages with foreach? or to run in a loop to print all the dlls in each package

Comment: `$FileLookup` is a [HastTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-hashtable?view=powershell-7.3). So you have `$FileLookup.Keys` for a list of packages, and you access the files in a package with: `$FileLookup[<Key>]`. To loop: `$FIleLookup.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { echo $_.Key ; echo ($_.Value -join ', ') }`.

Comment: Hi @Keith Miler, just want to verify, I have an empty Package File: (without value after the ':' ) in your solution  you won't take those right? and the files under

Comment: Just saw this. Will check after running errands.

Comment: `$FileLookup = Get-Content $FilePath | Select-String -Pattern '(?:Package\s+)?File.+?/?([^/]+)?$' | ForEach-Object -Begin { $hash = @{} ; $currKey = '' ; $nullCount = 0 } -Process { If ( $_.Matches.Groups[0].Value -match '^Package' ) { $currKey = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value ; If ( -not $currKey) { $currKey = '(none){0}' -f $nullCount } ; $currVal = @() ; $hash.Add($currKey , $currVal) } Else { $currVal = $hash[$currKey] + $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value ; $hash[$currKey] = $currVal } } -End { $hash }
`

Comment: Hi @Keith why you changed the code? what is the difference between the old one? Thanks

Comment: It handles package files with no name

Comment: Hi @Keith
Actually sometimes the Package File: is empty and sometime = '/' , I don't know if your solution covers this (the solution with the bash covers this cases). regardless your last update is not working. I get this message: WARNING: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ' '  Key being added: ' '"

Comment: Package File: can include name or '/' or empty for each case there are files under

Comment: Are you making any attempt to read, unsterstand, and modify the code I've already offered? Could any of this back and forth have been eliminated by explaining specifics and providing sample data that represented the conditions you're now descfribing? Start by examining the [`Select-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-string) output and how the captures changed with the modified [*regular expressions*](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html).

Comment: Nothing was change. I ran your last code and have an exception, WARNING: Exception calling "Add" with "2" argument(s): "Item has already been added. Key in dictionary: ' ' Key being added: ' '"

Comment: This solved the issue when there are more than 1 '/' . If ( -not $currKey) {
     $currKey = '(none){0}' -f $nullCount
     $nullCount = $nullCount + 1
     } 
But still failed when its empty. can you help me with that please?

Comment: I get an exception when there is 2 empty or more (only Package File: )

Comment: I mean that each '/' is replacing with (none){#} but not for an empty string after the :

Comment: At some point I lost the increment operator for `$nullCount`. Change `{ $currKey = '(none){0}' -f $nullCount }` to `{ $currKey = '(none){0}' -f $nullCount++ }`.

Comment: Hi, still has the issue for empty , do you know how to fix it? The If ( -not $currKey) does not catch the empty, only the /

Comment: It's working here...Try turning on verbosity and inserting `write-verbose  $currKey.Length` after the initial assignment.

Comment: after the initial assignment.? Can you tell me the right place? It’s not only a print? How it will help me with an empty string

Comment: According to https://regex101.com '/' is not a group but Package File: without anything (empty) is a group so If ( -not $currKey) don't catch it. maybe you have an idea how to solve it? I mean when its empty the name is not changing to none{#}

Comment: My code treats both as empty filemames. The initial assignment statement was `$currKey = $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value`

Comment: I am talking about empty package file: there is an error as I wrote before

Comment: So am I!!! WHY DON'T YOU EDIT THE SAMPLE DATA IN YOUR QUESTION TO INCLUDE EXAMPLES OF WHAT YOUR ARE TRYING TO DESCRIBE?????!!!!!??????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

within bash script:

```
$filePath = "path/to/your/file.txt"

# Read the file into an array of lines
$lines = Get-Content $filePath

# Initialize the result array
$result = @()

# Loop through the lines
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Length; $i++) {
    $line = $lines[$i]

    # Check if the line starts with "Package File:"
    if ($line -match "^Package File:\s+(.*)") {
        $packageName = $matches[1].TrimStart("/")
        $packageFiles = @()

        # Loop through the lines until the next "Package File:" or the end of the file
        for ($j = $i + 1; $j -lt $lines.Length; $j++) {
            $nextLine = $lines[$j]

            # Check if the line starts with "File:"
            if ($nextLine -match "^File:\s+(.*)") {
                $fileName = $matches[1]
                $packageFiles += $fileName
            }

            # Check if the line starts with "Package File:" or if this is the last line
            if ($nextLine -match "^Package File:" -or $j -eq $lines.Length - 1) {
                $result += @{
                    PackageName = $packageName
                    Files = $packageFiles
                }

                $i = $j - 1
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

# Output the result
$result
```

This script should read the file into an array of lines, loop through the lines, and split the file into sections from "Package File:" to "Package File:".

Comment: I'm confused: The question is about PowerShell and your code is PowerShell. How does Bash come into play?